# Как сделать Google Map внутри MockUp Макбука

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api, google-maps

Имеется мокап макбука и клиент хочет чтобы карта была непосредственно внутри макбука. Но я понятия не имею как это сделать? Есть какие-то предположения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для адаптации карты на сайте под любым разрешением можно использовать медиа-запросы `@media`. К примеру, если карта:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

имеет фиксированную высоту или ширину:

```
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

то для экранов шириной 960px или меньше можно подобрать нужный размер карты:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
   #map {
     height: 280px;
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

Карты по-умолчанию отлично работают с различными разрешениями экранов. Что бы лучше стилизовать ее, стоит так же обратиться в документацию google maps api.

Вот некоторые ресурсы, которые помогут вам с адаптацией под экраны:
[htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media)
[habr](https://habr.com/post/119127/)
[mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)